# Bootstrap chat widget on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

The chat widget on www.bestdealadvisors.com works great on the desktop but not on a mobile device. For example on the iPhone only half the widget is displayed and cannot be collapsed. 
Can someone show me the css needed to display the widget correctly on mobile devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the media queries to yield the best result.

You have the following element for the chat widget:

```
<div class="chatcontainer">
```

which has the following CSS style:

```
.chatcontainer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 65%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

The `left` property here causes the problem on mobile devices. Using a media query, you can override this property below certain resolutions: For example, you can write a media query to change it as follows below 768px:

```
.chatcontainer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 65%;
    bottom: 0;
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        left: 10%;
        right: 10%;
    }   
}
```

Bootstrap's main concept is that, while a few widgets can be placed on a row on web platforms, each widgets occupies one whole row on mobile devices. So that chat widget should occupy the whole row, without floating it to the right.

And for a better user experience, chat widget should be hidden at first, you can place a flat round button at bottom right to open the widget.

Comment: Can you show me the media query for this, thanks

Comment: @Danny I added an example, check it out.

Comment: That's great thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap. It provides auto shape. You just specify rates. It divide field to 12 pieces. for example .col-sm-4 's mean is that div has 4/12 rate of root tag's/field's.